# create table of contents in EPUB when converting from docx [pandoc]

Tags: pandoc, epub, epub3

I want to automate progress of converting some EPUBs to EPUBS with toc.
I first convert them to `docx` and by some tricks I change some paragraphs to `heading 1` when I convert them again to EPUB the headings have their heading style but there is nothing in table of contents.
If I create a word from scratch and use its default `heading 1` `pandoc` easily converts that to `EPUB` and create TOC as it should be.
Now I want a way to convert pandoc styles to something  like word styles.
This is my progress:

```
$ pandoc base.epub -o temp.docx
$ python do_magic_to_change_paragraphs_to_heading.py temp.docx # using docx package and I'm sure it's not the problem
$ pandoc temp.docx -o final.epub --toc
```

Comment: not sure what exactly your problem is, but you may want to use markdown instead of docx as an intermediate format (as it maps pretty much one to one to pandoc's internal document representation) – or even better, directly work on that internal AST with https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html

Comment: thanks, I check markdown as an intermediate and I tell you the result.